PHP won't run shell script
I'm trying to run a shell script with PHP using shell_exec() on an apache server.
I've tried changing the sudoers.d file, adding www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/sh, but that hasn't worked. I've also tried just giving it full access with www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL which didn't work either. In the error log it says "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper." However, I've tried using the -S option and it says no password was provided. I'd also like to not hard code a password in if that's possible.
Here's the PHP code:
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('sudo sh ./../connect.sh 2>&1');
?>


www-data is used when run as apache/nginx process. Do you run as cronjob?

shresolves to /usr/bin/sh on my system, not to /usr/sh.

Re "However, I've tried using the -S option and it says no password was provided.", Did you provide it?

Re "I'd also like to not hard code a password in if that's possible.", Are you asking how to read from a file?
